# Android Webview error when displaying a html message

Tags: android, android-webview

In our app sometimes the html pages displayed with webview are not shown properly. The use case is as following:

When I need to show a html message inside a webview(an email message) the page sometimes doesn't render properly and it doesn't show the original message at all.
The loadData is run on UI thread so no worries about that. 
I tried everything, no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, set the acceleration in developer options to false(it is false by default) if by any means it is set to true.
That should do the trick.